# Como inverter o lado que inicia os dígitos em um input HTML?

Tags: javascript, html5

Por exemplo na parte 'Numeral formatting' deste site https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

Quando digito, os números começam ser escritos da direita para a esquerda, e o padrão é de qualquer input é da esquerda para direita.

Como faço para alterar o input para que fique desta forma quando eu digitar?

Answer (score 6):

Não use `direction: rtl` para isso. Embora produza o resultado esperado, isso fere a semântica do HTML, uma vez que a proposta do RTL é indicar que o conteúdo daquele elemento está em um idioma que é escrito da direita para a esquerda: é uma propriedade de localização, não de formatação.

Como você quer apenas formatar o texto, utilize a propriedade de alinhamento de texto.

```css
input[type=number] {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Nossa, ainda bem que você respondeu essa pergunta. Eu não sabia da relação com idioma.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Site está aí para isso: compartilhar conhecimento :D

Comment: Vou aproveitar a dica e corrigir uma resposta antiga minha xD